# Estimating global affine brightness difference

Tags: variational-methods

Let $f$ and $g$ be two images. With two functions $a$ and $b$ the brightness difference of the images is to be estimated with the following functional
$E(a,b) = \int_{\Omega} (((a \cdot f+b)-g)^2 + \alpha a_x^2 + \beta b_x^2) dx$

How can I choose $\alpha$ and $\beta$ so that instead of the **lokal** affine brightness differences the **global** affine brightness differences are estimated?

$a$, and $b$ are the affine grey scale modifications (multiplicative and additive) with $a_x$, $b_x$ the first derivatives in $x$ direction.

Comment: if $a$ and $b$ are functions, what does $a\cdot b$ mean? what is $a_x$, $b_x$? Please properly define *all* your symbols, as in stating which domain of definition they map to which values.